# How do I access named capturing groups in a .NET Regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm having a hard time finding a good resource that explains how to use Named Capturing Groups in C#.  This is the code that I have so far:

```
string page = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytePage);
Regex qariRegex = new Regex("<td><a href=\"(?<link>.*?)\">(?<name>.*?)</a></td>");
MatchCollection mc = qariRegex.Matches(page);
CaptureCollection cc = mc[0].Captures;
MessageBox.Show(cc[0].ToString());
```

However this always just shows the full line:

```
<td><a href="/path/to/file">Name of File</a></td>
```

I have experimented with several other "methods" that I've found on various websites but I keep getting the same result.

How can I access the named capturing groups that are specified in my regex?

Comment: Backreference should be in the format (?<link>.*) and not (?<link>.*?)

Comment: FYI: If you are trying to store a named capture group inside an xml file then the `<>` will break it. You can use `(?'link'.*)` instead in this case. Not entirely relevant to this question but I landed here from a Google search of ".net named capture groups" so I'm sure other people are as well...

Comment: StackOverflow link with nice example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1381163/463206  Also, @rtpHarry, No the `<>` will not break it. I was able to use the `myRegex.GetGroupNames()` collection as the XML element names.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

Use the group collection of the Match object, indexing it with the capturing group name, e.g.

```
foreach (Match m in mc){
    MessageBox.Show(m.Groups["link"].Value);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `var m`, since that would be an `object`.

Answer (score 126):

You specify the named capture group string by passing it to the indexer of the `Groups` property of a resulting `Match` object.

Here is a small example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        String sample = "hello-world-";
        Regex regex = new Regex("-(?<test>[^-]*)-");

        Match match = regex.Match(sample);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["test"].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The following code sample, will match the pattern even in case of space characters in between.
i.e. :

```
<td><a href='/path/to/file'>Name of File</a></td>
```

as well as:

```
<td> <a      href='/path/to/file' >Name of File</a>  </td>
```

Method returns true or false, depending on whether the input htmlTd string matches the pattern or no. If it matches, the out params contain the link and name respectively.

```
/// <summary>
/// Assigns proper values to link and name, if the htmlId matches the pattern
/// </summary>
/// <returns>true if success, false otherwise</returns>
public static bool TryGetHrefDetails(string htmlTd, out string link, out string name)
{
    link = null;
    name = null;

    string pattern = "<td>\\s*<a\\s*href\\s*=\\s*(?:\"(?<link>[^\"]*)\"|(?<link>\\S+))\\s*>(?<name>.*)\\s*</a>\\s*</td>";

    if (Regex.IsMatch(htmlTd, pattern))
    {
        Regex r = new Regex(pattern,  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
        link = r.Match(htmlTd).Result("${link}");
        name = r.Match(htmlTd).Result("${name}");
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

I have tested this and it works correctly.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that curly braces can access the groups. I prefer to stick to `${1}` to keep things even simpler.

Comment: This completely answers the question, but has some problems that are too long to explain in here, but I explained and corrected those in [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58613327/146513)

Answer (score 3):

Additionally if someone have a use case where he needs group names before executing search on Regex object he can use:

```
var regex = new Regex(pattern); // initialized somewhere
// ...
var groupNames = regex.GetGroupNames();
```

Answer (score 2):

This answers improves on [Rashmi Pandit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/906847/146513), which is in a way better than the rest because that it seems to completely resolve the exact problem detailed in the question.

The bad part is that is inefficient and not uses the IgnoreCase option consistently.

Inefficient part is because regex can be expensive to construct and execute, and in that answer it could have been constructed just once (calling `Regex.IsMatch` was just constructing the regex again behind the scene). And `Match` method could have been called only once and stored in a variable and then `link`and `name` should call `Result` from that variable.

And the IgnoreCase option was only used in the `Match` part but not in the `Regex.IsMatch` part.

I also moved the Regex definition outside the method in order to construct it just once (I think is the sensible approach if we are storing that the assembly with the `RegexOptions.Compiled` option).

```
private static Regex hrefRegex = new Regex("<td>\\s*<a\\s*href\\s*=\\s*(?:\"(?<link>[^\"]*)\"|(?<link>\\S+))\\s*>(?<name>.*)\\s*</a>\\s*</td>",  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

public static bool TryGetHrefDetails(string htmlTd, out string link, out string name)
{
    var matches = hrefRegex.Match(htmlTd);
    if (matches.Success)
    {
        link = matches.Result("${link}");
        name = matches.Result("${name}");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        link = null;
        name = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```