# Iteration through GroupCollection in C#

Tags: c#, collections, loops

I'm currently trying to use regular expressions in C#:

```
Regex reg_gameinfo = new Regex(@"PokerStars Game #(?<HID>[0-9]+):\s+(?:HORSE)? \(?(?<GAME>Hold'em|Razz|7 Card Stud|Omaha|Omaha Hi/Lo|Badugi) (?<LIMIT>No Limit|Limit|Pot Limit),? \(?(?<CURRENCYSIGN>\$|)?(?<SB>[.0-9]+)/\$?(?<BB>[.0-9]+) (?<CURRENCY>.*)\) - (?<DATETIME>.*$)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Match matchresults = reg_gameinfo.Match(rawtext);
Dictionary<string,string> gameinfo = new Dictionary<string,string>();
if (matchresults.Success)
{
     gameinfo.Add("HID", matchresults.Groups["HID"].Value);
     gameinfo.Add("GAME", matchresults.Groups["GAME"].Value);
     ...
}
```

Can I iterate through the `matchresult.Groups` GroupCollection and add the key-value pairs to my `gameinfo` dictionary?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(See this question: [Regex: get the name of captured groups in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381097/regex-get-the-name-of-captured-groups-in-c))

You can use [GetGroupNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.getgroupnames.aspx):

```
Regex reg_gameinfo = new Regex(@"PokerStars Game #(?<HID>[0-9]+):\s+(?:HORSE)? \(?(?<GAME>Hold'em|Razz|7 Card Stud|Omaha|Omaha Hi/Lo|Badugi) (?<LIMIT>No Limit|Limit|Pot Limit),? \(?(?<CURRENCYSIGN>\$|)?(?<SB>[.0-9]+)/\$?(?<BB>[.0-9]+) (?<CURRENCY>.*)\) - (?<DATETIME>.*$)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Match matchresults = reg_gameinfo.Match(rawtext);
Dictionary<string,string> gameinfo = new Dictionary<string,string>();

if (matchresults.Success)
    foreach(string groupName in reg_gameinfo.GetGroupNames())
        gameinfo.Add(groupName, matchresults.Groups[groupName].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put the group names into a list and iterate over it. Something like

```
List<string> groupNames = ...
foreach (string g in groupNames) {
    gameinfo.Add(g, matchresults.Groups[g].Value);
}
```

But make sure to check whether the group exists.