# Regex get Group Names?

Tags: swift

Looking for a way to get Group Names using Swift, I found info using GetGroupNames in C# ([How do I get the name of captured groups in a C# Regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381097/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-captured-groups-in-a-c-sharp-regex)) but can't find anything similar. Want to be able to tell is a group exists.

At the moment using code below ...

```
let search = "Agora.2010.1080p.BluRay.x264.mp4"
let regex "^(Agora.)(?<"group name">2010)?"
let return_results = regex(for: regex, in: search)

func regex(for expression: String, in string: String) -> [String]? {

    guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: expression, options: [.caseInsensitive]) else { return nil }
    let results = regex.matches(in: string, range: NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string))
    guard !results.isEmpty else { return nil }

    var values: [String] = []
    guard regex.numberOfCaptureGroups > 0 else { return nil }

    for r in 1...(regex.numberOfCaptureGroups) {
        let range = results[0].range(at: r)

        if range.length > 0 {
            let start = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location)
            let end = string.index(start, offsetBy: range.length)
            let value = string[start..<end]
            if !value.isEmpty {
                let value_string = String(value)
                values.append(value_string)
            }
        }
    }
    return values
```

At the moment this just looks for any groups. What I want is to return is a Dictionary list of ["group name":"value"]. I've tried from attached link ... "regex.Match(line).Groups" & "regex.GetGroupNames()" which do not exist.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and clearly show a good example of your input, desired output, and actual output.

Comment: Ok, added Search string & Regex.

Comment: Again, what is your actual and desired results? It's not clear what your question is.