# C# Regex, extract strings by reference string

Tags: c#, regex, extract

Edit: Solution by @Heinzi
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1731641/87698

---

I got two strings, for example `someText-test-stringSomeMoreText?` and some kind of pattern string like this one `{0}test-string{1}?`.

I'm trying to extract the substrings from the first string that match the position of the placeholders in the second string.

The resulting substrings should be: `someText-` and `SomeMoreText`.

I tried to extract with `Regex.Split("someText-test-stringSomeMoreText?", "[.]*test-string[.]*\?"`. However this doesn't work.

I hope somebody has another idea...

Comment: why not `Regex.Split(input,"test-string")`

Comment: There's nothing built-in in the framework, but someone already implemented an algorithm to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1731641/87698

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing formatted string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410012/parsing-formatted-string)

Comment: Great, exactly what I ws looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to use named groups:

```
(?<prefix>.*)test-string(?<suffix>.*)\?
```

This will return 2 groups containing the wanted prefix and the suffix.

```
var match = Regex.Match("someText-test-stringSomeMoreText?", 
    @"(?<prefix>.*)test-string(?<suffix>.*)\?");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["prefix"]);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["suffix"]);
```

Comment: The problem is, those two input strings are completely variable. The second string could also look like `{0}test{1}stringSome{2}Text?` for example. The problem is, I'm looking for a way to create a working regex pattern from this pseudo pattern string dynamicaly.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution, at least its a bit dynamical.

First I split up the pattern string `{0}test-string{1}?` with 
`string[] patternElements = Regex.Split(inputPattern, @"(\\\{[a-zA-Z0-9]*\})");`

Then I spit up the input string `someText-test-stringSomeMoreText?` with 
`string[] inputElements = inputString.Split(patternElements, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Now the `inputElements` are the text pieces corresponding to the placeholders `{0},{1},...`