# How to stop RichTextBox Inline from being deleted in TextChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I've been tasked with creating a partially editable `RichTextBox`. I've seen suggestions in Xaml adding `TextBlock` elements for the `ReadOnly` sections, however this has the undesireable visual effect of not wrapping nicely. (*It should appear as a single block of continuous text.*)

I've patched together a working prototype using some [reverse string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1731641/3773066) to restrict/allow edits and coupled that with dynamic creation of [inline `Run` elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run(v=vs.110).aspx) for displaying purposes. Using a dictionary to store the current values of the editable sections of text, I update the `Run` elements accordingly upon any `TextChanged` event trigger - with the idea that if an editable section's text is completely deleted, it will be replaced back to its default value.

In the string: *"Hi NAME, welcome to SPORT camp."*, only *NAME* and *SPORT* are editable.

```
                ╔═══════╦════════╗                    ╔═══════╦════════╗
Default values: ║ Key   ║ Value  ║    Edited values:  ║ Key   ║ Value  ║
                ╠═══════╬════════╣                    ╠═══════╬════════╣
                ║ NAME  ║ NAME   ║                    ║ NAME  ║ John   ║
                ║ SPORT ║ SPORT  ║                    ║ SPORT ║ Tennis ║
                ╚═══════╩════════╝                    ╚═══════╩════════╝

 "Hi NAME, welcome to SPORT camp."    "Hi John, welcome to Tennis camp."
```

**Problem**:

Deleting the entire text value in a particular run removes that run (and the following run) from the `RichTextBox Document`. Even though I add them all back, they no longer display correctly on screen. For example, using the edited string from the above setup:

- User highlights the text *"John"* and clicks <kbd>Delete</kbd>, instead of saving the empty value, it should be replaced with the default text of *"NAME"*. Internally this happens. The dictionary gets the correct value, the `Run.Text` has the value, the `Document` contains all the correct `Run` elements. But the screen displays:

  - Expected: *"Hi NAME, welcome to Tennis camp."*
  - Actual: *"Hi NAMETennis camp."*

[image: Actual vs Expected screenshot]

*Sidenote*: This loss-of-Run-element behavior can also be duplicated when pasting. Highlight *"SPORT"* and paste *"Tennis"* and the Run containing *" camp."* is lost.

**Question**:

How do I keep every `Run` element visible even through destructive actions, once they've been replaced?

**Code**:

I have tried to strip down the code to a minimum example, so I've removed:

- Every `DependencyProperty` and associated binding in the xaml
- Logic recalculating caret position (*sorry*)
- Refactored the linked string formatting extension methods from the first link to a single method contained *within* the class. (Note: this method will work for simple example string formats. My code for more robust formatting has been excluded. So please stick to the example provided for these testing purposes.)
- Made the editable sections clearly visible, nevermind the color scheme.

To test, drop the class into your WPF project Resource folder, fix the namespace, and add the control to a View.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WPFTest.Resources
{
  public class MyRichTextBox : RichTextBox
  {
    public MyRichTextBox()
    {
      this.TextChanged += MyRichTextBox_TextChanged;
      this.Background = Brushes.LightGray;

      this.Parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      this.Parameters.Add("NAME", "NAME");
      this.Parameters.Add("SPORT", "SPORT");

      this.Format = "Hi {0}, welcome to {1} camp.";
      this.Text = string.Format(this.Format, this.Parameters.Values.ToArray<string>());

      this.Runs = new List<Run>()
      {
        new Run() { Background = Brushes.LightGray, Tag = "Hi " },
        new Run() { Background = Brushes.Black, Foreground = Brushes.White, Tag = "NAME" },
        new Run() { Background = Brushes.LightGray, Tag = ", welcome to " },
        new Run() { Background = Brushes.Black, Foreground = Brushes.White, Tag = "SPORT" },
        new Run() { Background = Brushes.LightGray, Tag = " camp." },
      };

      this.UpdateRuns();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Parameters { get; set; }
    public List<Run> Runs { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }

    private void MyRichTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      string richText = new TextRange(this.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock.ContentStart, this.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock.ContentEnd).Text;
      string[] oldValues = this.Parameters.Values.ToArray<string>();
      string[] newValues = null;

      bool extracted = this.TryParseExact(richText, this.Format, out newValues);

      if (extracted)
      {
        var changed = newValues.Select((x, i) => new { NewVal = x, Index = i }).Where(x => x.NewVal != oldValues[x.Index]).FirstOrDefault();
        string key = this.Parameters.Keys.ElementAt(changed.Index);
        this.Parameters[key] = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newValues[changed.Index]) ? key : newValues[changed.Index];

        this.Text = richText;
      }
      else
      {
        e.Handled = true;
      }

      this.UpdateRuns();
    }

    private void UpdateRuns()
    {
      this.TextChanged -= this.MyRichTextBox_TextChanged;

      foreach (Run run in this.Runs)
      {
        string value = run.Tag.ToString();

        if (this.Parameters.ContainsKey(value))
        {
          run.Text = this.Parameters[value];
        }
        else
        {
          run.Text = value;
        }
      }

      Paragraph p = this.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock as Paragraph;
      p.Inlines.Clear();
      p.Inlines.AddRange(this.Runs);

      this.TextChanged += this.MyRichTextBox_TextChanged;
    }

    public bool TryParseExact(string data, string format, out string[] values)
    {
      int tokenCount = 0;
      format = Regex.Escape(format).Replace("\\{", "{");
      format = string.Format("^{0}$", format);

      while (true)
      {
        string token = string.Format("{{{0}}}", tokenCount);

        if (!format.Contains(token))
        {
          break;
        }

        format = format.Replace(token, string.Format("(?'group{0}'.*)", tokenCount++));
      }

      RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;

      Match match = new Regex(format, options).Match(data);

      if (tokenCount != (match.Groups.Count - 1))
      {
        values = new string[] { };
        return false;
      }
      else
      {
        values = new string[tokenCount];

        for (int index = 0; index < tokenCount; index++)
        {
          values[index] = match.Groups[string.Format("group{0}", index)].Value;
        }

        return true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `RichTextBox` provides much more than a mere text editor through the `FlowDocument` class. This makes it a handy control for displaying formatted text, images, tables, and even `UIElements`. However all these come with the cost of complexity. Therefore, dealing with `RichTextBox` can be rather messy. Is there any chance you can switch to a more convenient control like `AvalonEdit` which is better suited for text processing?

Comment: From what I can see the problem is that `TryParseExact(richText` fails. Is it reasonable to start fixing it?

Comment: @qqww2 I'm not familiar with `AvalonEdit` or it's licensing requirements, but I will consider it.

Comment: @OhBeWise Sorry, maybe I'm wrong or I'm misunderstanding your requirements. I'm trying to run your code and I see that - if I delete "SPORT" (for example) - then `bool extracted` is false... I would go on fixing this, if it makes sense...

Comment: @MachineLearning Ah, you are probably dbl-click highlighting so when you try to delete "SPORT" it detects you trying to delete "SPORT " with the space - and the space isn't editable. I've actually overridden the highlighting behavior because of this error.  I just didn't include it in this example - so sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when you change the text via user interface, internal `Run` objects are modified, created, deleted, and all the crazy things occur behind the scenes. The internal structure is very complex. For example here is a method which is called deep inside the innocent single line `p.Inlines.Clear();`:

```
private int DeleteContentFromSiblingTree(SplayTreeNode containingNode, TextPointer startPosition, TextPointer endPosition, bool newFirstIMEVisibleNode, out int charCount)
{
    SplayTreeNode leftSubTree;
    SplayTreeNode middleSubTree;
    SplayTreeNode rightSubTree;
    SplayTreeNode rootNode;
    TextTreeNode previousNode;
    ElementEdge previousEdge;
    TextTreeNode nextNode;
    ElementEdge nextEdge;
    int symbolCount;
    int symbolOffset;

    // Early out in the no-op case. CutContent can't handle an empty content span.
    if (startPosition.CompareTo(endPosition) == 0)
    {
        if (newFirstIMEVisibleNode)
        {
            UpdateContainerSymbolCount(containingNode, /* symbolCount */ 0, /* charCount */ -1);
        }
        charCount = 0;
        return 0;
    }

    // Get the symbol offset now before the CutContent call invalidates startPosition.
    symbolOffset = startPosition.GetSymbolOffset();

    // Do the cut.  middleSubTree is what we want to remove.
    symbolCount = CutContent(startPosition, endPosition, out charCount, out leftSubTree, out middleSubTree, out rightSubTree);

    // We need to remember the original previous/next node for the span
    // we're about to drop, so any orphaned positions can find their way
    // back.
    if (middleSubTree != null)
    {
        if (leftSubTree != null)
        {
            previousNode = (TextTreeNode)leftSubTree.GetMaxSibling();
            previousEdge = ElementEdge.AfterEnd;
        }
        else
        {
            previousNode = (TextTreeNode)containingNode;
            previousEdge = ElementEdge.AfterStart;
        }
        if (rightSubTree != null)
        {
            nextNode = (TextTreeNode)rightSubTree.GetMinSibling();
            nextEdge = ElementEdge.BeforeStart;
        }
        else
        {
            nextNode = (TextTreeNode)containingNode;
            nextEdge = ElementEdge.BeforeEnd;
        }

        // Increment previous/nextNode reference counts. This may involve
        // splitting a text node, so we use refs.
        AdjustRefCountsForContentDelete(ref previousNode, previousEdge, ref nextNode, nextEdge, (TextTreeNode)middleSubTree);

        // Make sure left/rightSubTree stay local roots, we might
        // have inserted new elements in the AdjustRefCountsForContentDelete call.
        if (leftSubTree != null)
        {
            leftSubTree.Splay();
        }
        if (rightSubTree != null)
        {
            rightSubTree.Splay();
        }
        // Similarly, middleSubtree might not be a local root any more,
        // so splay it too.
        middleSubTree.Splay();

        // Note TextContainer now has no references to middleSubTree, if there are
        // no orphaned positions this allocation won't be kept around.
        Invariant.Assert(middleSubTree.ParentNode == null, "Assigning fixup node to parented child!");
        middleSubTree.ParentNode = new TextTreeFixupNode(previousNode, previousEdge, nextNode, nextEdge);
    }

    // Put left/right sub trees back into the TextContainer.
    rootNode = TextTreeNode.Join(leftSubTree, rightSubTree);
    containingNode.ContainedNode = rootNode;
    if (rootNode != null)
    {
        rootNode.ParentNode = containingNode;
    }

    if (symbolCount > 0)
    {
        int nextNodeCharDelta = 0;
        if (newFirstIMEVisibleNode)
        {
            // The following node is the new first ime visible sibling.
            // It just moved, and loses an edge character.
            nextNodeCharDelta = -1;
        }

        UpdateContainerSymbolCount(containingNode, -symbolCount, -charCount + nextNodeCharDelta);
        TextTreeText.RemoveText(_rootNode.RootTextBlock, symbolOffset, symbolCount);
        NextGeneration(true /* deletedContent */);

        // Notify the TextElement of a content change. Note that any full TextElements
        // between startPosition and endPosition will be handled by CutTopLevelLogicalNodes,
        // which will move them from this tree to their own private trees without changing
        // their contents.
        Invariant.Assert(startPosition.Parent == endPosition.Parent);
        TextElement textElement = startPosition.Parent as TextElement;
        if (textElement != null)
        {               
            textElement.OnTextUpdated();                    
        }
    }

    return symbolCount;
}
```

You can look at the source code from [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/R/3c8da4f43a4659e9.html) if you are interested.

A solution is do not use the `Run` objects you created for comparison purposes directly in the `FlowDocument`. Always make a copy of it before adding them:

```
private void UpdateRuns()
{
    TextChanged -= MyRichTextBox_TextChanged;

    List<Run> runs = new List<Run>();
    foreach (Run run in Runs)
    {
        Run newRun;
        string value = run.Tag.ToString();

        if (Parameters.ContainsKey(value))
        {
            newRun = new Run(Parameters[value]);
        }
        else
        {
            newRun = new Run(value);
        }

        newRun.Background = run.Background;
        newRun.Foreground = run.Foreground;

        runs.Add(newRun);
    }

    Paragraph p = Document.Blocks.FirstBlock as Paragraph;
    p.Inlines.Clear();
    p.Inlines.AddRange(runs);

    TextChanged += MyRichTextBox_TextChanged;
}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I did to solve this but I didn't really understand *why* it was a solution, but I suspected something under the hood was *remembering* the re-added Run was deleted. I couldn't agree more with "*crazy things occur behind the scenes*." Trying to fix the caret positioning for instance... algorithmic nightmare which I'm trying to simplify - so many edge cases. Thanks for the link to the source.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to move the code to create the Runs in the UpdateRuns

```
    private void UpdateRuns()
    {
        this.TextChanged -= this.MyRichTextBox_TextChanged;

        this.Runs = new List<Run>()
  {
    new Run() { Background = Brushes.LightGray, Tag = "Hi " },
    new Run() { Background = Brushes.Black, Foreground = Brushes.White, Tag = "NAME" },
    new Run() { Background = Brushes.LightGray, Tag = ", welcome to " },
    new Run() { Background = Brushes.Black, Foreground = Brushes.White, Tag = "SPORT" },
    new Run() { Background = Brushes.LightGray, Tag = " camp." },
  };

        foreach (Run run in this.Runs)
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. It was similar to what I had done and qqww2 had reaffirmed for me. The other approach was better suited outside this simple example when bindings and `DependencyProperty` were the data sources and it helped provide more of *the why* I needed. Still, have a +1 for your troubles and my thanks!