# Extracting multiple values from String with regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract some data from a file to convert it to an object in order to be processed.

I receive the data in a text file with the following format:

```
Card 1: 32 45 ... 88  1
```

And my model is:

```
public class Card {
    private Integer id;
    private List<Integer> values;
    // getters and setters
}
```

So in this example the object would be (as JSON):

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "values": [32, 45, ..., 88, 1]
}
```

*Note: In the model the numbers are formatted ad `%2d`, so between `88` and `1` there are 2 spaces*

My goal is to extract all the data using `Pattern` and `Matcher` to get a cleaner solution than a workaround with `String#split()`.

After checking some posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59631818/5310721) and the linked ones from there, I got to the conclusion that I can extract the `id` field with something like

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("Card\\s+(\\d+):(\\s+(\\d+))+").matcher(input);
Integer id = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
```

But I don't know how to extract the `values` list from the input. Is it possible to extract the values from this input using this approach? It should be something like

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("Card\\s+(\\d+):(\\s+(\\d+))+").matcher(input);
Integer id = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    values.add(m.group()); // or some other iteration to get groups from 2 to N
}
```

Let me know if there is another info or clarification needed. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: You can't use `Integer id = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));` before actually running `m.find()`.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/tA2hhQ, does it do what you need?

Comment: you're right, my bad. I wrote the snippet like that just to demonstrate the data extraction without the required boilerplate

Comment: String.split is the better solution, you can set one of your capture groups as everything after the colon and then split using whitespace

Comment: Why do you think what you propose is cleaner than `String.split()`?  And how are you reading in the data?  And why worry about the spacing between the values or the magnitude of the values?  Are you trying to verify the format?

Comment: A decent JSON parser would parse the data quickly, efficiently, and correctly.

Comment: I wonder which is the (bigger) workaround: `split` or an *complicated* regular expression...

Comment: `String[] a = s.replaceAll("[^\\d ]", "").trim().split(" +");` The first element is the ID, the rest the values

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels OPs input is a text file, not JSON (that was their sample output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would still use split.

- split the string on any combo of spaces and colons.
- then skip the first value (the string `card`) and collect into a list
- then post process the list and populate the Card instance.

```
String input = "Card 1: 32 45 99 44 33 88  1";


Card firstCard = Arrays.stream(input.split("[:\\s]+")).skip(1)
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                lst->new Card(lst.get(0), new ArrayList<>(lst.subList(1, lst.size())))));

System.out.println(firstCard);
```

prints

```
card = 1 : [32, 45, 99, 44, 33, 88, 1]
```

`Collectors.toList()` is immutable.  So I pass the `sublist` to `new ArrayList<>()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to match the format of the lines first and use 2 capture groups for the data that you want to get.

If there is a match, you can then split the value of group 2 on one or more spaces.

```
^Card\h+(\d+):\h*(\d+(?:\h+\d+)*)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `Card\h+` Match `Card` and 1 or more horizontal whitespace chars
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits
- `:\h*` Match a colon and optional spaces
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\d+(?:\h+\d+)*` Match 1+ digits, and then optionally repeat 1+ spaces and 1+ digits
- `)` Close group 2
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WMNf2t/1)

If the capture group 2 can also be empty, then you can make what is [inside the group optional](https://regex101.com/r/ViOWAw/1).

```
String regex = "^Card\\h+(\\d+):\\h*(\\d+(?:\\h+\\d+)*)$";
String s = "Card 1: 32 45 88  1";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

while (matcher.find()) {
    Card card = new Card(
        Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)),
        Arrays.stream(matcher.group(2).split("\\h+"))
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
}
```

If you print card as json, the result is:

```
{"id":1,"values":[32,45,88,1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split once on non-digits and convert to Integers:

```
List<Integer> nums = Arrays.stream(line.split("\\D+")).skip(1).map(Integer::valueOf).toList();
```

Then use it for both id and values:

```
Card card = new Card(nums.get(0), nums.subList(1, nums.size()));
```

Comment: That would have to be `List<Integer> nums = Arrays.stream(line.split("\\D+")).skip(1).map(Integer::valueOf).toList();
`

Comment: @g00se quite right. Corrected.