# Automatically extract classes from a generated file

Tags: c#, regex

I have a file that is generated containing multiple classes that I want to split into multiple files each one containing just one class.
The code is in c#

Is there a program that can do this (preferably with source code available)? Is there a simple Regex that can extract the classes/interfaces?

Comment: Have a look at that question: It uses regular expression to capture well defined C# classes Regular Expressions to find C# class and method names

Comment: If you are cleaning up a C# project in Visual Studio you can use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/): Right click the project and on the menu select _Refactor_ => _Move Types Into Matching Files...__.

Comment: @RamiHelmy where's the link?

Comment: Sorry, here it is:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593136/regular-expressions-to-find-c-sharp-class-and-method-names

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `Regex` would be the correct strategy to parse C# code. It could probably works in some simple cases but you probably face some situation tricking you. Think as an example about having some commentend unbalanced `'{'` in the code.
I suggest to you to investigate this other SO question: [Parser for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81406/parser-for-c-sharp) about how to parse c# code.

Comment: If you properly understand the language (inluding commenting), regex is fine. How do you think the compilers lexer works?

Comment: @Gusdor lexer is just a step in compiling. Think why in sharpdevelop they use a parser instead of plain regex for intellisense.

Comment: What I was trying to get at is that it is possible because the language has a defined structure. Regex is just a parsing script. It works char-at-a-time, not line-by-line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with [Visual Studio Macro Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b4c73967%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If that's a one off, do the least thing that (quickly) works. So if it is just one or a few files and you're not after a very generic solution, I would identify all the headers (`public class Foo` and the like), for example with the help of Notepad++ and a recorded macro, manually correcting the results, and then I'd write a little C# program to split the file in places where these headers are