# how to use regex class for string maniplations

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on string maniplations using regex.

```
   Source: string value = @"/webdav/MyPublication/Building%20Blocks/folder0/folder1/content_1.xml";

   output required:
           Foldername: folder1
           content name: content
           folderpath:/webdav/MyPublication/Building%20Blocks/folder0/folder1/
```

I am new to this, can any one say how it can be done using regex.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you describe the rules you want to use in words? An example can be interpreted in various ways. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: The `Path` class will probably be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules you need seem to be the following:

- Folder name = last string preceding a '/' character but not containing a '/' character
- content name = last string not containing a '/' character until (but not including) a '_' or '.' character
- folderpath = same as folder name except it can contain a '/' character

Assuming the rules above - you probably want this code:

```
string value = @"/webdav/MyPublication/Building%20Blocks/folder0/folder1/content_1.xml";

var foldernameMatch = Regex.Match(value, @"([^/]+)/[^/]+$");
var contentnameMatch = Regex.Match(value, @"([^/_\.]+)[_\.][^/]*$");
var folderpathMatch = Regex.Match(value, @"(.*/)[^/]*$");
if (foldernameMatch.Success && contentnameMatch.Success && folderpathMatch.Success)
{
    var foldername = foldernameMatch.Groups[1].Value;
    var contentname = contentnameMatch.Groups[1].Value;
    var folderpath = folderpathMatch.Groups[1].Value;
}
else
{
  // handle bad input
}
```

Note that you can also combine these to become one large regex, although it can be more cumbersome to follow (if it weren't already):

```
var matches = Regex.Match(value, @"(.*/)([^/]+)/([^/_\.]+)[_\.][^/]*$");
if (matches.Success)
{
    var foldername = matches.Groups[2].Value;
    var contentname = matches.Groups[3].Value;
    var folderpath = matches.Groups[1].Value + foldername + "/";
}
else
{
    // handle bad input
}
```

Comment: Thank you Pinny. The content may or may not contain a '_'. If it contains, i need to remove it, or else have to take the name as it is.

Comment: If it doesn't contain an underscore - e.g. 'content.xml' do you need to take the whole name or until the '.' character?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [named captures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906493/regex-named-capturing-groups-in-net), but you're probably better off (from a security and implementation aspect) just using the [Uri class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jeff Moser on this one, but to answer the original question, I believe the following regular expression would work:
`^(\/.+\/)(.+?)\/(.+?)\.`

edit: Added example.

```
var value = "/webdav/MyPublication/Building%20Blocks/folder0/folder1/content_1.xml";
var regex = Regex.Match(value, @"^(\/.+\/)(.+?)\/(.+?)\.");

// check if success
if (regex.Success)
{
    // asssign the values from the regular expression
    var folderName = regex.Groups[2].Value;
    var contentName = regex.Groups[3].Value;
    var folderPath = regex.Groups[1].Value;
}
```