# Read a particular line in a string?

Tags: c#

Here is my string line:

```
string conSTR = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDB;User ID=sa";
```

I just want to get the string `"(local)"`, and `"MyDb"` and `"sa"` word anybody can suggest how to do it in C#.

Comment: You should take a look at some regular expressions. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717707/best-way-to-split-a-string-without-a-sperator/11717893#11717893

Comment: Best way is to use SqlConnectionStringBuilder class

Comment: Do you want to parse connection strings, or you question is more generic one?

Comment: @Serg, I will not use this to just parse a connection string to connect to connect to sql db, I will also use this to connect my connection properties on connecting my crystal report like this crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "(local)";
            crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "MyDB";
            crConnectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
            crConnectionInfo.Password = "";

Comment: Use Skeet's answer than.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming this is actually a SQL connection string, you could use [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) - pass the string into the constructor, then interrogate the appropriate properties.

Comment: Thank you very much! People like you is a blessing for us who are just beginner to c# and .net!

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7z89tex.aspx):

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(conSTR);
```

Then you can read the builder's properties, like [.`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.datasource.aspx), [`.UserID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.userid.aspx) and [`.Password`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.password.aspx).