# Regex capturing

Tags: c#, regex

I am having trouble capturing a value from a string. I only want the number I don't want to capture the `T` or `:`. This failing test explains:

```
[TestMethod]
public void RegExTest()
{
    var rex = new Regex("^T([0-9]+):"); //as far as I understand, the () denote the capture group
    var match = rex.Match("T12:abc");
    Assert.IsTrue(match.Success);
    Assert.IsTrue(match.Groups[0].Success);
    Assert.AreEqual("12", match.Groups[0].Captures[0]); //fails, actual is "T12:"
}
```

Comment: Whatever you don't want to capture you must denote it. Your regex should be `^(?:T)([0-9]+)(?:\:)$`

Comment: @AndreCalil I see, yes that works, except I have to use `Groups[1]` to get the result. Thanks.

Comment: The first group is Groups[1]. Groups[0] is the whole match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups collection, which is zero based, denotes capturing groups from index 1.
`Groups[0]` always indicates the entire match.
Hence you need to do `Groups[1]` instead of `Groups[0]` above.

> The MatchGroups property returns a GroupCollection object that
>   contains Group objects that represent captured groups in a single
>   match. The first Group object in the collection (at index 0)
>   represents the entire match. Each object that follows represents the
>   results of a single capturing group.

[The Group Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to match digits between **T** and **:**

Here is a simple `Regex` for that

```
@"(?<=T)\d+(?=:)"//no need of groups here
```

**About your Regex:**

your regex

```
^T([0-9]+):
```

should be like this

```
T(\d+)://^ is not needed and [0-9] can be represented as \d
```

Here

```
Group[0] would be T:12//a full match
Group[1] would be 12//1st match within ()i.e.1st ()
Group[2] would be //2nd match within ()i.e 2nd ()
```

Comment: Thanks, the `^` is to ensure that the T is at the start of the string. So I do need that don't I?

Comment: no you don't need it...
if you use `^` then a string **sddsT55:** would not match since `^` means that you want T at the begging.So a string **T55:** would match with `^` but not **sddsT55:**

Comment: @weston if you are sure that the `string` would be always `T54:` then you should use `^`

Comment: Yeah I'm sure, see my next question makes it clearer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077136/regex-extract-optional-group

Answer (score 0):

Got it by naming the group.

```
[TestMethod]
public void RegExTest()
{
    var rex = new Regex("^T(?<N>[0-9]+):");
    var match = rex.Match("T12:abc");
    Assert.IsTrue(match.Success);
    Assert.IsTrue(match.Groups[0].Success);
    Assert.AreEqual("12", match.Groups["N"].Value);
}
```

Should have looked harder: [How do I access named capturing groups in a .NET Regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906493/regex-named-capturing-groups-in-net)

Comment: Well, congrats for answering your own question. Could you give a try to my suggestion, anyway?

Comment: @AndreCalil I did, and it works, but like I said only by accessing `Group[1]`, which actually as Kash points out works without changing the expression.