# rewrite VBScript.Regex to C# Regex code

Tags: c#, regex, vbscript

I have a legacy code written in VBScript that uses regular expressions
I need to rewrite this code in c#.
Unfortunately I can't map VBScript RegEx class with "Submatches" collection to respective C# code.

This is VBScript:
    RegExp=CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp");
    RegExp.Pattern = ' some pattern
    RegExp.IgnoreCase=True;
    RegExp.Global=True;
    RegExp.Multiline=True;

```
Matches=RegExp.Execute(someText);
For Each Match In Matches Do
    If Match.SubMatches(4) <> Nothing Then
    ' some code goes next
```

Problem is: I can't figure out what is the equivalent C# Regex methods for "Submatches" of VBScript.

My C#:

```
        var Regex = new Regex(@"(\{\n?)|(""(""""|[^""]*)*"")|([^\},\{]+)|(,\n?)|(\}\n?)",  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        var Matches = Regex.G(textBox1.Text);

        var Tree = new SimpleTree<string>();

        foreach (var Match in Matches)
        {

        }
```

the "Match" object in the "foreach" loop is an "object" and has no any "Submatch" members.
How to implement Submatches in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(\{\n?)|(""(""""|[^""]*)*"")|([^\},\{]+)|(,\n?)|(\}\n?)",  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
MatchCollection matches = re.Matches(textBox1.Text);

var Tree = new SimpleTree<string>();

foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    if( m.Groups(4).Value  != null )
    {
          // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, but there's another trouble. Groups indexes are not the same and results are different

Comment: Check out this example: (You need to use Result class)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906493/regex-named-capturing-groups-in-net