# Regex group empty

Tags: c#, regex

This is my code:

```
private static Regex paginationRegex = new Regex("<div class=\"pagination\">.*?<ul>(?<lis>.*?)</ul></div>",
                            RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string output = File.ReadAllText("output.html");

            var match = paginationRegex.Match(output);

            var lis = match.Groups["lis"].Value;

        }
```

and this is my `HTML` in output.html:

```
<div class="pagination">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:searchPage('1')" class="arrowDeactiveLeftFirst"> </a></li>  
                            <li><a href="javascript:searchPage('1')" class="deActivateleftArrow"> </a></li>
                    <li>
                                    <a class="current" href="javascript:searchPage('1')">1</a>
                                </li>
          <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:searchPage('2')">2</a> 
                                </li>
          <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:searchPage('3')">3</a> 
                                </li>
                      <li><a href="javascript:searchPage('2')" class="rightArrow"> </a></li>
                          <li><a href="javascript:searchPage('730')" class="arrowRightLast"> </a></li>
              </ul>
      </div>
```

However the `lis` group is always empty. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean `<li>` instead of `<lis>`?

Comment: he means var lis  @AndrewWhitaker

Comment: @Neel: Right, I understand that `var lis` is empty, but the Regex is looking for a tag named `<lis>`. I'm asking if this should be `<li>` instead.

Comment: @Andrew and Charlie Hardis: It is called "Named Groupes" I am capturing groups. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906493/regex-named-capturing-groups-in-net

Comment: @Jack: You're right. Didn't even know those existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just because you're not taking into account the space between the `</ul>` and the `</div>` at the end of your snippet. Allowing whitespace in between the two seems to fix the issue:

```
//                                                                                  \/
Regex paginationRegex = new Regex("<div class=\"pagination\">.*?<ul>(?<lis>.*?)</ul>\\s*</div>",
                        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

I'm also obliged to mention that regular expressions often aren't the best tool for parsing HTML. Check out [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for a good library that's great at parsing HTML.