# Sum numbers within string

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim strOrig = "192/8' 33/5' 76/24' 17/12'"
```

Hi all, I want to obtain every number before the "/". The output will be 318.
Regarding how to achieve it, what I can think of is:

1.Split all the segment by looking for 'spacing' as end point for each segment and put them into an array. E.g. (0)192/8, (1)33/5, (2)76/24 etc...

2.By looping the array, look for the slash "/" and get the number before it and sum it until loop end. E.g. (0)192, (1)33, (2)76 etc...

I would like to know if my method was worth the effort as I would like to learn any MORE effective ways than this. Thanks all.

Comment: is this always that formatting? (e.g. number/number)

Comment: I would say that it is (number/string) due to there is a single quote behind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
Dim strOrig = "192/8' 33/5' 76/24' 17/12'"
Dim numbers = From word In strOrig.Split()
              Let number = word.Split("/"c).First().Trim().TryGetInt32()
              Where number.HasValue
              Select number.Value

Dim sum As Int32 = numbers.Sum()  ' 318
```

I've used following extension to try-parse a string to `Integer?`:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function TryGetInt32(Str As String) As Nullable(Of Int32)
    If Str Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
    Dim num As Int32
    If Int32.TryParse(Str, num) Then Return num
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: (don't forget the VB.NET line-continuation underscore in that LINQ)

Comment: @valverij: not needed with VS 2010

Comment: Any particular reason to choose `Int32` over `Integer` ?

Comment: Really? Is that a VS 2010 thing or a .NET 4.5 thing? I definitely remember needing it in 2010

Comment: @valverij: i'm using VS 2010 since 2011 and no, you don't need it anymore. I prefer Int32  over Integer because it is shorter and Int32 is also clearer since there are also Int16 and Int64 and the UInt variants.

Comment: @4LeaveCover: i think that you then really need the line continuation characters. Try to append `_`(empty space and underscore) at the end of each line in the query. Here is an example: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Implicit-Line-Continuation-a044cbe0

Comment: After I apply _ behind the extension, it throws me error Type 'Extension' is not defined.

Comment: @4LeaveCover: the extension method `TryGetInt32` must be in a module like following: `Module StringExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Function TryGetInt32(Str As String) As Nullable(Of Int32)
        If Str Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
        Dim num As Int32
        If Int32.TryParse(Str, num) Then Return num
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Module`. But remember to add `Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices` at the top.

Answer (score 1):

[Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906493/regex-named-capturing-groups-in-net) to the rescue:

```
    Dim strOrig As String = "192/8' 33/5' 76/24' 17/12'"

    Dim sum as Integer = (From m As Match In Regex.Matches(strOrig, "(?<number>\d+?)/")
                          Select Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups("number").Value)
                         ).Sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple I can think of.

```
    Dim lst As List(Of String) = strOrig.Split("/").ToList

    lst.RemoveAt(lst.Count - 1)
    lst.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToUInt16(x))
```