# Match anything between special characters in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this
[test]][test][test]

I would like with a regex to obtain a collection of elements where each element will be a value between the brackets [] :

test
test
test

With this code:

```
var pattern = @"\[(.*?)\]";            
var results = Regex.Matches("[test]][test][test]", pattern);
```

I managed to get the values but they include the brackets [] :

[test]
[test]
[test]

Comment: You just need to get the values from the first captured group `$1`

Comment: Also see [How do I access named capturing groups in a .NET Regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906493/how-do-i-access-named-capturing-groups-in-a-net-regex)

Comment: did my answer help you solving your problem?

Answer (score 1):

This should works for you:

```
var pattern = @"\[(?<elem>.*?)\]";
var results = Regex.Matches("[test1]][test2][test3]", pattern);

foreach (Match item in results)
    Console.WriteLine(item.Groups["elem"]);
```