# How the Regex C# Regex groups are identified

Tags: c#, regex

I have a Regex expression:

```
@"(?<one>M\/S\s(\w+?\s)+(?<two>(U22334)))"
```

...which is tested against the string:

```
"M/S ALPHA DAILY LIVING PRODUCTS INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED  U22334"
```

My desktop Hero Regex tester shows that there is one match and four groups as follows.

```
1: LIMITED

2: U22334

one: M/S ALPHA DAILY LIVING PRODUCTS INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED  U22334

two: U22334
```

I would like to know how the these groups are determined. Any help would be appreciated very much.

Comment: .NET differs from from other flavors in that non-named groups are numbered independently from named groups.  Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: I don't know whether it is a duplicate. This problem has destroyed my two days. That is the reason I posted this question. To an extent the answer of Rudis was satisfying to me although I am yet to gain proficiency with iteration through foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Group 1 is defined by `(\w+?\s)` and it captures only last iteration
- Group 2 is defined by `(U22334)`
- Named group `one` is defined with whole regex definition
- Named group `two` is defined by `(?<two>(U22334))`

For detailed explanation you can use e.g. page [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/23XpZD/1) (*this link is with your regex pattern and tested string*)

Comment: Now I understand a bit from the explanation of Rudis. Thank you @Rudis. So in my case if I iterate with a foreach loop, will it go through the loop four times in my case. I am so confused about its iteration through foreach....loop.

Comment: You can read named groups directly by name - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906493/how-do-i-access-named-capturing-groups-in-a-net-regex

Comment: Okay. Thank you. And I will do that. After my problem is solved, I will write what I did as suggested by you.

Comment: I would have loved to post how I understood my problem as an answer to those who are starting out with Regex capturing group. But it seems that since this is marked duplicate I am unable to do it.