# Regex to match multiple number groups between two characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string that looks like the following:

```
<@399969178745962506> hello to <@!104729417217032192>
```

I have a dictionary containing both that looks like following:

```
{"399969178745962506", "One"},
{"104729417217032192", "Two"}
```

My goal here is to replace the `<@399969178745962506>` into the value of that number key, which in this case would be `One`

```
Regex.Replace(arg.Content, "(?<=<)(.*?)(?=>)", m => userDic.ContainsKey(m.Value) ? userDic[m.Value] : m.Value);
```

My current regex is as following: `(?<=<)(.*?)(?=>)` which only matches everything in between `<` and `>` which would in this case leave both `@399969178745962506` and `@!104729417217032192`

I can't just ignore the `@` sign, because the `!` sign is not there every time. So it could be optimal to only get numbers with something like `\d+`

I need to figure out how to only get the numbers between `<` and `>` but I can't for the life of me figure out how.

Very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract just the numbers from you're given format, use this regex pattern:

```
(?<=<@|<@!)(\d+)(?=>)
```

See it work in action: https://regexr.com/3j6ia

Answer (score 3):

In C#, you may use 2 approaches: a lookaround based on (since lookbehind patterns can be variable width) and a capturing group approach.

## Lookaround based approach

The pattern that will easily help you get the digits in the right context is

```
(?<=<@!?)\d+(?=>)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%3C%40!%3F%29%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3D%3E%29&i=%3C%40399969178745962506%3E%20hello%20to%20%3C%40!104729417217032192%3E)

The `(?<=<@!?)` is a positive lookbehind that requires `<=` or `<=!` immediately to the left of the current location and `(?=>)` is a positive lookahead that requires `>` char immediately to the right of the current location.

## Capturing approach

You may use the following pattern that will *capture* the digits inside the expected `<...>` substrings:

```
<@!?(\d+)>
```

**Details**

- `<@` - a literal `<@` substring
- `!?` - an optional exclamation sign
- `(\d+)` - capturing group 1 that matches one or more digits
- `>` - a literal `>` sign.

Note that the values you need can be accessed via `match.Groups[1].Value` as shown in the snippet above.

Usage:

```
var userDic = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"399969178745962506", "One"},
        {"104729417217032192", "Two"}
    };
var p =  @"<@!?(\d+)>";
var s = "<@399969178745962506> hello to <@!104729417217032192>";
Console.WriteLine(
    Regex.Replace(s, p, m => userDic.ContainsKey(m.Groups[1].Value) ?
        userDic[m.Groups[1].Value] : m.Value
    )
); // => One hello to Two
// Or, if you need to keep <@, <@! and >
Console.WriteLine(
    Regex.Replace(s, @"(<@!?)(\d+)>", m => userDic.ContainsKey(m.Groups[2].Value) ?
        $"{m.Groups[1].Value}{userDic[m.Groups[2].Value]}>" : m.Value
    )
); // => <@One> hello to <@!Two>
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/hjvWEe).

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-capturing groups to exclude parts of the needed pattern to be inside the group:

```
(?<=<)(?:@?!?)(.*?)(?=>)
```

alternativly you could name the inner group and use the named group to get it:

```
(?<=<)(?:@?!?)(?<yourgroupname>.*?)(?=>)
```

Access it via `m.Groups["yourgroupname"].Value` - more see f.e. [How do I access named capturing groups in a .NET Regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906493/how-do-i-access-named-capturing-groups-in-a-net-regex)

Comment: Is there no way to just get the numbers within that capture? So that `<@399969178745962506> hello to <@!104729417217032192>` becomes  `[0] = 399969178745962506, [1] = 104729417217032192`

Comment: @Ezzy make the `@` and `!` optional in a `non-capturing` group before the `.*` - see change

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: `(?:<@!?(\d+)>)`

**Details**:

`(?:)` Non-capturing group

`<@` matches the characters <@ literally

`?` Matches between zero and one times

`(\d+)` 1st Capturing Group `\d+` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bwzY83/2)

```
string text = "<@399969178745962506> hello to <@!104729417217032192>";
Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "399969178745962506", "One" }, { "104729417217032192", "Two" } };

text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?:<@!?(\d+)>)", m => list.ContainsKey(m.Groups[1].Value) ? list[m.Groups[1].Value] : m.Value);

Console.WriteLine(text); \\ One hello to Two
Console.ReadLine();
```