# Regex to match a Number between two strings

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get the regex to extract all numbers located between the / character and the - character in a web address.

ex.
https://example.com/myfirstlink/1737-mypage.html
Should return 1737

and

https://anotherexample.com/second/536-page456.html
Should return 536

Any ideas / suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Actually I have tried a few things but can't get it to work, here's how far I've gotten 
(?<=\/)([0-9])(?=\-)

Comment: Great, please add it to the question and describe the problem you have with the regex. It looks like you missed `+` after `[0-9]`. See https://regex101.com/r/kbVyrQ/1. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253155/regex-to-match-multiple-number-groups-between-two-characters)  I re-linked to.